# visual studio msvc not allowing long if-else nesting

Tags: visual-studio-2019, msvc12

i have a piece of code:

```
                       for(int l=0; l<schedule_display_field->children_fields.size();l++){
                          auto field  = schedule_display_field->children_fields[l];
                            int field_index = boq_interface->schedule->get_index_of_field(field);
                            if(field->get_data_type() == "number"){
                                if(field->id == "sr_num"){
                                    multi_data_array.push_back(to_string(index));
                                    index++;
                                }else{
                                    multi_data_array.push_back(to_string((*i)->cells_data[field_index]->numberic_data));
                                }
                            }else if(field->get_data_type() == "image"){
                                multi_data_array.push_back((*i)->cells_data[field_index]->image_url);
                            }else if(field->get_data_type() == "text"){
                                multi_data_array.push_back((*i)->cells_data[field_index]->text_data);
                            }
                        }
```

here visual studio 2019 msvc is complaining:
**Severity Error    C1061   compiler limit: blocks nested too deeply**  at the line `if(field->id == "sr_num"){`

on looking for reasons, i found out that msvc does not allow nested blocks beyond 128 blocks, is there any way to change this setting in visual studio 2019 or maybe any other solution.

Comment: Could you add a complete example where the issue can be reproduced!? I don't like to rebuild the surunding environment for this snippet...
Thx

Comment: 128-deep nested blocks! Wow - I think you need to reconsider your design.

Comment: Unless this code is machine-generated, I cannot imagine how you would ever end up with this deep of nesting. You need to fix the code, not work around the compiler's limitations. These are perfectly reasonable limitations. You evidently didn't show all of your code; what you've shown here is < 5 levels deep.